# Filter rows based on column value condition and merge with other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df1 = 
       vol           comp        sort
      vol1           10          20
      vol2           10          20      
      

df2 = 

 load         vol          counter_name       counter_value
 1            vol1         bytes_read            50
 1            vol1         bytes_written         50
 1            vol1         stage                 comp
 1            vol2         bytes_read            50
 1            vol2         stage                 sort
 1            vol2         bytes_written         50

 2            vol1         bytes_read            150
 2            vol1         bytes_written         250
 2            vol1         stage                 done
 2            vol2         bytes_read            50
 2            vol2         stage                 comp
 2            vol2         bytes_written         1250
```

I need to add "bytes_read", "bytes_written" field from df2 "counter_name" column to df1, when stage is "done" for each vol in "volume" volumn. When stage is not "done" then we can just make it NAN.

Output should be

```
   df1 = 
       vol            comp        sort     bytes_read     bytes_written
      vol1           10          20         150            250
      vol2           10          20         NaN            NAN
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/17071908/16815358

Comment: @TinoD: Thanks for the link, but I dont think it answers my question. I need to filter df2 based on column_Value and counter_name pairs .and then merge with df1 on same volumes

Answer (score 0):

Reshape with [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), filter the rows with [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and combiné with [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
out = (
 df1.merge(
    df2.pivot(index=['load', 'vol'], columns='counter_name', values='counter_value')
       .query('stage == "done"')
       .reset_index(),
    on='vol', how='left')
 )
```

Output:

```
    vol  comp  sort  load bytes_read bytes_written stage
0  vol1    10    20   2.0        150           250  done
1  vol2    10    20   NaN        NaN           NaN   NaN
```

Variant:

```
out = (
 df1.merge(
    df2.pivot(index=['load', 'vol'], columns='counter_name', values='counter_value')
       .loc[lambda x: x.pop('stage')=='done']
       .astype(float)
       .reset_index(),
    on='vol', how='left')
 )
```

Output:

```
    vol  comp  sort  load  bytes_read  bytes_written
0  vol1    10    20   2.0       150.0          250.0
1  vol2    10    20   NaN         NaN            NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. But I get the following error,

ValueError: Length of passed values is 4992, index implies 2

Comment: Please edit the question and provide the output of `df2.to_dict('list')` and your pandas version (`pd.__version__`)